# download file with curl via sftp

Tags: php, curl, sftp

This only creates an empty file.. No content in the file

```
$host = 'domain.com';
$pass = 'xxx';

$remote = 'sftp://var/www/test.txt';
$local = 'C:\wamp\www\test.txt';

$curl = curl_init();
$file = fopen($local, 'w');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $remote);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "root:$pass");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
fclose($file);
```

## solution

```
$host = 'domain.com';
$pass = 'xxx';

$remote = "sftp://root:$pass@$host/var/www/test.txt";
$local = 'C:\wamp\www\test.txt';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $remote);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "root:$pass");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
file_put_contents($local, curl_exec($curl));
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$d = curl_exec($curl);
// data is in $d var, write it somewhere ;)
$local = "/tmp/myfile.txt";
file_put_contents($local, $d);
```

Comment: Edited.  Set return transfer, put a var to place the return in.  Then write the file or whatever....

Comment: In your case, you'd use fwrite().  But unless you're on a very old version of PHP, I'd chuck fopen and fclose and fwrite and just use file_put_contents().

Comment: $remote = 'sftp://var/www/test.txt'; isn't valid either.

Comment: $remote = 'sftp://username@hostname.tld/path/to/file.txt';